# Ecommerce website not taking custom variables {{ }}

Tags: angularjs, yeoman-generator-angular, moltin

I'm watching [this video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gLa2LxMdAPs) on building an e-commerce site with Angular and Moltin. I've gotten to the 19 minute mark where he begins creating the product.html view.

I'm not sure why, but I can console.log(product) just fine, but when I try to use variables like {{ product.title} in my product.html view, it doesn't show. Plain text shows up fine, and in my category.html view I can get my categories to ng-repeat using {{ category.title }} just fine.

I am not sure why I can log the product object, but the view will not render it.

Here's a [link](http://github.com/qdechery/testStore/tree/master/app) to my GitHub repo. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: posting your code would help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a scope conflict being caused because you are declaring product to be your controller with the `controllerAs` statement [here](https://github.com/qdechery/testStore/blob/master/app/scripts/app.js#L77), and then setting `$scope.product` in your controller [here](https://github.com/qdechery/testStore/blob/master/app/scripts/controllers/product.js#L12)

You need to resolve this conflict by either renaming `$scope.product` to something else in the controller, or renaming your `controllerAs: 'product'` statement.

I was able to make this work by changing `controllerAs:'product'` to `controllerAs:'prod'`, but any solution resolving the conflict between the variable names should work.

Comment: Thank you! That did work - simply changing the controllerAs: product to controllerAs: prod

Answer (score 0):

Could you provide any snippets or a fiddle of when you initialize products? Just from glancing at the video it seems that the promise from your ProductCtrl might not be fulfilled by the time you are invoking the console.log(); What value are you getting when you console.log()?

Also, although this doesn't seem to be the issue- I have seen the same issue when [binding to primitive](http://www.codelord.net/2014/05/10/understanding-angulars-magic-dont-bind-to-primitives/) types!

A simple check could be trying to instantiate the product to an empty object: $scope.product = {}; somewhere in the same context BEFORE you are setting to new value- that way angular's magic will know to watch and bind that object in the digest cycle.

Comment: Thank for you reply, Nathan. Here is a link to a github repo: https://github.com/qdechery/testStore/tree/master/app  - you can check out the /scripts/controllers folder and look at product.js for the ProductCtrl controller. Also, to answer your question, when I console.log() out, I get an Object with the correct product id, title, slug, and everything.